# Shell merge two file

Tags: linux, shell, join, awk

I have two files and  I want to join file1 and file2 by matching second and first fields in file1 and file2 and write first data from file1 to file2

file1:

```
5439725407 uQkiJRPOZLLJkc
5368657511 eWGDnOcNgxjBK
5322202068 dNsUkWOMk9lNJ
```

file2:

```
uQkiJRPOZLLJkc,00087b8dbe6fdc3a5725a0a77fa4e37f3db10440d8b0da2d3935cb0f8f4f9089,1
eWGDnOcNgxjBK,0008958b743f8b786fa7f080348f3180f8e410890a07995878c1fcbda66706b4,1
dNsUkWOMk9lNJ,0008bc14ecce6150bef44f657e12314b8b2c37a5730bf88fc81b66d5f77ed8be,1
```

outputfile:

```
uQkiJRPOZLLJkc,00087b8dbe6fdc3a5725a0a77fa4e37f3db10440d8b0da2d3935cb0f8f4f9089,1,5439725407
eWGDnOcNgxjBK,0008958b743f8b786fa7f080348f3180f8e410890a07995878c1fcbda66706b4,1,5368657511
dNsUkWOMk9lNJ,0008bc14ecce6150bef44f657e12314b8b2c37a5730bf88fc81b66d5f77ed8be,1,5322202068
```

Comment: Did you review `man join` before asking a question here?

Comment: OP, please always use code tags for sample Inputs and sample output in your posts, as per forum rules.

Comment: yes i did it, but ı couldnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` solution may also help you.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} ($2 in a){print a[$2] "," $1}' FS="," filE2  FS=" " filE1
```

Output will be as follows.

```
uQkiJRPOZLLJkc,00087b8dbe6fdc3a5725a0a77fa4e37f3db10440d8b0da2d3935cb0f8f4f9089,1,5439725407
eWGDnOcNgxjBK,0008958b743f8b786fa7f080348f3180f8e410890a07995878c1fcbda66706b4,1,5368657511
dNsUkWOMk9lNJ,0008bc14ecce6150bef44f657e12314b8b2c37a5730bf88fc81b66d5f77ed8be,1,5322202068
```

***EDIT:*** Adding explanation with non-one liner form of solution too here now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{                      ##Checking condition here FNR==NR, which will be TRUE when first Input_file will be read.
  a[$1]=$0;                   ##Creating an array named a whose index is first field of current line and value is current line.
  next                        ##next statement will skip all further statements.
}                             ##Following block will be executed when 2nd Input_file is being read.
($2 in a){                    ##checking if 2nd field of current line is present in array a, if yes then do following.
  print a[$2] "," $1          ##Printing the value of array a whose index is $2 of current line, printing comma and then printing first field of current line.
}
' FS="," filE2  FS=" " filE1  ##Setting field separator as comma for Input_file2 and setting field separator as space for Input_file1 here.
```

Answer (score 0):

**awk** solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}{ print $1,$2,$3,($1 in a? a[$1]:"") }' file1 FS=',' OFS=',' file2
```

The output:

```
uQkiJRPOZLLJkc,00087b8dbe6fdc3a5725a0a77fa4e37f3db10440d8b0da2d3935cb0f8f4f9089,1,5439725407
eWGDnOcNgxjBK,0008958b743f8b786fa7f080348f3180f8e410890a07995878c1fcbda66706b4,1,5368657511
dNsUkWOMk9lNJ,0008bc14ecce6150bef44f657e12314b8b2c37a5730bf88fc81b66d5f77ed8be,1,5322202068
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want (your fileX format is a little off I think)

```
    cat file2 | tr \, ' ' | join -1 1 -2 2 - file1 | tr ' ' \,
```

Comment: You can use tr ' ' ',' <file1 | join -t ',' -1 1 -2 2 file2 -